# Loop is completing before all the promises responses do

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have this function where i need to combine multiple promises responses, but after some reading i realized promises are async so in this case my loop is going to complete before all the responses do. Should i need to use something like $q.all in this case? How can i improve this piece of code? Thanks..

```
$scope.messages = [];

function getPastMessages(data) {
  angular.forEach(data, function(item) {            
    Message.get(item.id).then(function(msg) {
      if (msg.data.is_private === false) {
        User.getPictures(msg.data.user.id).then(function(pics) {
          msg.data.user.pictures = pics.data;
        });
      } else {
        User.get(msg.data.im.sender).then(function(sender) {
          msg.data.im.sender = sender.data;
          User.get(msg.data.im.reciever).then(function(reciever) {
            msg.data.im.reciever = reciever.data;
          });                       
        });
      }
      console.log(msg.data); // SHOW 4 OBJECTS CORRECT
      $scope.messages.push(msg.data);
      console.log($scope.messages); // SHOW ARRAY OF 6 OBJECTS    ????????
    })
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a working example it was difficult to fully understand the context of your code, but you can do something similar to this.

The basic idea is to create a list of promises that you need to wait for. Each of the promises within this list should return a result (presumably `msg.data`). Using `$q.all`, you'll get a list of results (one from each promise) at the end. Note that things returned within a `.then` get wrapped in promises if they aren't already promises.

```
$scope.messages = [];

function getPastMessages(data) {
  var promises = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function(item) {            
    promises.push(getMessage(item));
  });
  return $q.all(promises);
}

function getMessage(item) {
  return Message.get(item.id).then(function(msg) {
    if (msg.data.is_private === false) {
      return User.getPictures(msg.data.user.id).then(function(pics) {
        msg.data.user.pictures = pics.data;
        return msg.data;
      });
    } else {
      return User.get(msg.data.im.sender).then(function(sender) {
        msg.data.im.sender = sender.data;
        return User.get(msg.data.im.reciever).then(function(reciever) {
          msg.data.im.reciever = reciever.data;
          return msg.data;
        });                       
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
getPastMessages(data).then(function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    $scope.messages.push(results[i]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only rely on promises to have resolved when you're inside their callback functions.

```
var messages = [];
somethingAsync().then(function(data){
  messages.push(data);
});
console.log(messages.length)
```

might return `0` or `1` depending on how long somethingAsync takes; you can't rely on it having completed.

Instead you should do your debugging from *inside* the callback function:

```
var messages = [];
somethingAsync().then(function(data){
  messages.push(data);
  console.log(messages.length)
});
```

This will always return `1`.